# Why would pipe-> finalize not be called for an observable when the observable completes, but a callback in subscribe would be called?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I am working on code that needs to take some action when an observable completes. I was originally using `pipe(finalize(() => {}))`, but I was finding that when the observable completes, the finalize callback was not being called. When I switched from a pipe to a subscription, then completion callback is called.

In the code below, "completed?" prints, but "Finalize called" does not

```
this.sweepRunner.start(parameters).then(output => {
        this.output = output;
        output.subscribe(null, null, () => {
            console.log("This will be called");
        });
        output.pipe(finalize(() => {
            console.log("This won't be called")}))
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point is that you `subscribe` to `output` and not to `output.pipe(...)`.

In other words, `output.pipe(finalize(....))` creates a new Observable starting from the `output` Observable. So the code should look like this

```
this.sweepRunner.start(parameters).then(output => {
        const newObservable = output.pipe(finalize(() => {
            console.log("Finalize called");
            this.stateController.requestAction(
                this.stateController.patchActionFor<IDetectionLaserMotorState>(StateProperties.detectionMotorState)({
                    LRPosition: this.optimalState.position}))}))


        newObservable.subscribe(null, null, () => {
            console.log("completed?");
        });
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question so I edited it to make the question clearer. I understand that finalize returns a new observable, but the documentation states "Returns an Observable that mirrors the source Observable, but will call a specified function when the source terminates on complete or error. The specified function will also be called when the subscriber explicitly unsubscribes." In this case, finalize is not calling my function when the source observable completes

Comment: Maybe my answer was not clear, but the problem is not in `finalize` but in the fact that you FIRST `subscribe` to `output` and THEN you do the `output.pipe(..)`. So you `subscribe` to something which has no `finalize` attached to it in a pipeline. What you have to do is `output.pipe(finalize(...)).subscribe(...)`